# Можно ли добавить опцию существующему свойству формы?

Tags: lsfusion

При добавлении свойств в структуру формы существует возможность добавления опций свойствам формы. Например так:

```
MODULE Main;

CLASS LockedField;
text = DATA STRING[10] (LockedField);
isLock = DATA BOOLEAN (LockedField);

// здесь я добавляю свойство 'text' сразу с 
// опцией 'READONLYIF'
FORM lockedField
    OBJECTS lf = LockedField
    PROPERTIES (lf) text READONLYIF isLock(lf), isLock, NEW, DELETE 
;

NAVIGATOR {
    NEW lockedField FIRST;
}
```

Можно ли подобным образом добавить опцию уже добавленному свойству?
Например:

```
MODULE Main;

CLASS LockedField;
text = DATA STRING[10] (LockedField);

// Здесь в структуру формы я добавляю свойство
// 'text' без опций
FORM lockedField
    OBJECTS lf = LockedField
    PROPERTIES (lf) text, NEW, DELETE 
;

isLock = DATA BOOLEAN (LockedField);

// а здесь свойству 'text' нужно добавить
//  опцию 'READONLYIF'
EXTEND FORM lockedField
    PROPERTIES (lf) isLock
;

NAVIGATOR {
    NEW lockedField FIRST;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В 3-й версии такой возможности пока нет. Но такая возможность скорее всего будет добавлена в следующей [4-й](https://github.com/lsfusion/platform/issues/300) версии. Соответственно выглядеть будет как и остальные EXTEND (то есть просто добавлением впереди EXTEND):

```
EXTEND FORM lockedField
    EXTEND PROPERTIES (lf) text READONLYIF isLock(lf);
;
```

Пока в качестве workaround (правда неполного) можно использовать ABSTRACT:

```
// объявляем свойство, которое по умолчанию NULL, то есть text всегда будет доступен для записи
isLock = ABSTRACT BOOLEAN (LockedField);
FORM lockedField
    OBJECTS lf = LockedField
    PROPERTIES (lf) text READONLYIF isLock(lf)
;

// добавляем реализацию, которая будет ограничивать запись
shouldBeLocked = DATA BOOLEAN (LockedField);
isLock(LockedField lf) += shouldBeLocked(lf);
```